# Featured image from post not showing although Fb Debugger is OK

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

I´m finishing my site in WP and everything seems ok but I can´t get the featured image from my posts to show when sharing the link in FB.

I tryed the debugger, it sees the image ok and returnes a 200 response code.

[Debugger test result here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.momento-marketing.es/analitica-web/que-es-la-analitica-web/)

The image size is 300x227 so I understand there is no problem regarding size or proportion.

The Meta included about the image is http://www.momento-marketing.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Blog-Analitica-300x227.jpg'/>

Does anyone has a clue about this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have experienced this problem and found the fix - in my case it was connected to a plugin called Shareaholic. See this post for more info and the fix, including a screenshot showing the relevant checkbox - https://plus.google.com/106203314085966263136/posts/7xpLkaB41Ag

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced very wobbly Facebook behavior recently, ie the last few days. Putting page through the Facebook debugger (with og image correctly specified), it says that a particular image is less than 200 x 200 when it is considerably more than this.

Several pages that used to give thumbnails very happily no longer do. Yet one with a really big image (for the sake of Pinterest) with the image reduced in size on the page, is fine.

One thing that DOES upset Facebook - the image has to be hosted on precisely the same domain as the page. I found that when I used a shortened version of my domain name (which forwards to the full one), that prevented thumbnails appearing. Suspect that even a subdomain for one, and not the other, might upset things.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here...when you try to share it on your browser trough the mobile website, it shows the image.. Try to share a link and replace https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= to https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= and you see it works, so must be a problem in the desktop Facebook website

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has changed its requirements for showing images on facebook timeline or on a facebook page. Even I experimented a lot of things and finally found out a solution. Here is how to do it,

1. Download WPSSO plugin from wordpress.com
2. Install the plugin
3. Then navigate into the plugin settings and find the "Images" tab
4. Set "Open graph Dimensions" as 600 x 315
5. Now use images above the size of 600 x 315 in your posts
6. Cick save settings and now try debugging the post with your facebook debugger tool. 
   I am sure this will solve your problem. If problems persist do post them we will try to reslve it.

Note - This tutorial was taken from this link [Facebook image problem resolution](http://facebook.idroidwarz.com/2015/08/01/how-to-resolve-facebook-thumbnail-issue/#more-6)